# Is there a way to SEARCH (not FILTER) to a first match row in AG-GRID?

Tags: javascript, search, ag-grid

I want to implement a SEARCH BOX that moves the grid pointer (selected row) to the first match of the search criteria. I DO NOT want to FILTER the grid to show only those matches. I want all active rows to remain active (either all records or whatever filter condition is active at the moment of SEARCH). The key is, I only want the search result to change the ROW SELECTED in the grid and only to the first match, without changing the filter condition. AG-GRID seems to intermingle SEARCH and FILTER as if they were one and the same thing and they most certainly are NOT the same thing. Any help or guidance anyone can offer would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: The difference between "_search_" and "_filter_" in this context is, that you make a copy of the filtered data, and then use the copy to move the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by:

- iterating over all grid nodes via `api.forEachNode` to find the nodes that match the search text and store them in an array
- take the first item of the array and call `node.setSelected(true)` to select the node. You can also scroll to the `rowIndex` of that node by calling `api.ensureIndexVisible` or `api.ensureNodeVisible`: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grid-api/#reference-scrolling

Please see this sample which implements this: https://plnkr.co/edit/1x8NobmsGoHVTVUS

Comment: Thanks for your great guidance. The concepts of your solution make sense to me. I was hoping for something more built-in to the grid api but I should be able to apply the knowledge you imparted. Unfortunately, the Plunker example you linked to didn't quite execute. The text box acts as if there is no bind between the value there and the grid. I cloned the files locally and opened in VS Code and a local browser instance. Same result. Grid functions but no visible change of state in the grid from any input in the text box. That all said, you gave me a lot to go on. Will keep trying. Peace.

Comment: No problem :)
That's because I've bound the onChange method to the input box, this means that you have to press enter every time you want the grid to search for the text. You can use other events like onkeyup / onkeydown if you want to have the grid search based on every key press.